# no se ha dado ningun argumento que corresponda al parametro en C#

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, .net

Primero que nada soy algo nuevo en C# tengo este problema:

Este es en mi formulario donde pienso mostrar los datos en un datagridview al cargar 
private void mostrarAdmin()

```
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = mostrarAdminis.LstAdministradores();
    }
```

Me dice que no se ha dado ningun argumento cuando ya lo di en mi capa datos, creo que me he saltado algo tengo todas las referencias en orden y pues es el unico error que tengo hasta el momento.

```
public partial class ListarAdministradores : Form
{
    L_Administracion mostrarAdminis = new L_Administracion();
    public ListarAdministradores()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ListarAdministradores_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mostrarAdmin();
    }
    private void mostrarAdmin()
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = mostrarAdminis.LstAdministradores();
    }
 }
```

Esta es mi capa datos, aqui hago todas las conexiones y los objetos con la llamada a la base de datos.

```
 public DataTable LtarAdministrador(string parametro)
    {
        DataSet dts = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            cmd.Connection = cnx;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "sp_select_administrador";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@usuario", parametro));
            SqlDataAdapter miada;
            miada = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            miada.Fill(dts, "administracion");
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        }
        return (dts.Tables["administracion"]);
    }
```

y esta mi capa lógica, aqui esta solo el fragmento de código que utilizo para listar los administradores

```
    public DataTable LstAdministradores (string Parametro)
    {
        return _AdministradorDatos.LtarAdministrador(Parametro);
    }
```

y esta mi entidad, donde tengo todas las clases

```
public class E_Administracion
{

    private string User, Password, Cargo;
    private int ID, DUI;
    public string UserAdministrador
    {
        get { return User; }
        set { User = value; }
    }
    public string PasswordAdministrador
    {
        get { return Password; }
        set { Password = value; }
    }

    public string CargoAdministrador
    {
        get { return Cargo; }
        set { Cargo = value; }
    }

    public int IDAdministrador
    {
        get { return ID; }
        set { ID = value; }
    }

    public int DUIAdministrador
    {
        get { return DUI; }
        set { DUI = value; }
    }
}
```

que me hace falta?

Comment: Puedes probar agregar en `ListarAdministradores_Load` el `InitializeComponent();`

Comment: Si te dice que falta un argumento es por que falta un argumento, en tu capa datos no diste un argumento, declaraste un procedimiento ´public DataTable LtarAdministrador(string parametro)´ que requiere un argumento de nombre ´parametro´, cada ves que llames a este procedimiento, tienes que pasarle un argumento de tipo ´string´ si no siempre te dará el mismo error.

Answer (score 0):

Te falta pasarle el parametro en tu metodo, el mismo recibe un parametro string

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = mostrarAdminis.LstAdministradores("Aqui Falta el parametro");
```

En tu capa de datos pide un parámetro pero no se lo estas haciendo llegar desde la vista.